# how to upload pdf file?

Tags: android, file-upload

I am trying to upload pdf files to a server with the following code. I am using `uploadservice library` and it is working well with small file. But when I upload larger pdf files, it takes too much time and it gives me "error during upload" on completion. I changed the limit of uploads and post values on the server.

My question: is the error that I get while uploading large files is from internet speed or this library does not upload large files?

```
if (path == null) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please move your .pdf file to internal storage and retry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, myuploaduri)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "pdf") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And this is my log

> 07-18 00:15:18.280 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:18.281 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:18.726 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker I/View: Touch down dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{41ec73c0 VFED..C. ........ 0,96-720,192 #7f080035 app:id/button_upload}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=481.33148, y[0]=80.73535, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=5759257, downTime=5759257, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
>   07-18 00:15:18.737 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:18.739 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:18.775 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:18.777 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:18.801 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker I/View: Touch up dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{41ec73c0 VFED..C. ...P.... 0,96-720,192 #7f080035 app:id/button_upload}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=481.33148, y[0]=80.73535, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=5759331, downTime=5759257, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
>   07-18 00:15:18.801 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker V/Provider/Settings:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
>   07-18 00:15:18.805 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/ActivityThread: hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@43924e40,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@439259d8
>   07-18 00:15:18.812 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker E/preparing upload :: /storage/sdcard0/Download/1197.pdf
>   07-18 00:15:18.816 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker E/start: uploading
>   07-18 00:15:18.820 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:18.822 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:18.823 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@43928498 className=net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadService packageName=com.salahahmed.zaker intent=null}
>   07-18 00:15:18.826 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@43928498 className=net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadService packageName=com.salahahmed.zaker intent=null}
>       SVC-Calling onStartCommand: net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadService@43929c70, flags=0, startId=1
>   07-18 00:15:18.829 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=128KB
>       create new thread
>   07-18 00:15:18.830 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: new thread created
>       update thread list
>   07-18 00:15:18.830 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: threadid=17: interp stack at 0x63091000
>       threadid=17: created from interp
>   07-18 00:15:18.831 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: start new thread
>   07-18 00:15:18.831 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: threadid=17: notify debugger
>       threadid=17 (pool-6-thread-1): calling run()
>   07-18 00:15:18.834 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@43928498 startId=1 args=Intent { act=com.salahahmed.zaker.uploadservice.action.upload cmp=com.salahahmed.zaker/net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadService (has extras) }}
>   07-18 00:15:18.887 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: abdosalahas108.000webhostapp.com get result from proxy >>
>   07-18 00:15:18.888 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker I/System.out: propertyValue:true
>   07-18 00:15:18.889 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:18000000
>   07-18 00:15:18.889 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker I/System.out: [socket][4] connection abdosalahas108.000webhostapp.com/145.14.145.22:80;LocalPort=51788(18000000)
>       [CDS]connect[abdosalahas108.000webhostapp.com/145.14.145.22:80] tm:18000
>   07-18 00:15:18.890 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.salahahmed.zaker :80 
>   07-18 00:15:19.114 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.1.4:51788] connected
>       [CDS]rx timeout:18000000
>   07-18 00:15:19.289 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:19.291 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:19.785 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:19.786 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:20.039 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:15:20.041 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x616b4bd8>
>   07-18 00:17:13.099 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker I/System.out: [CDS]write is:2144/4096
>       [CDS]write exceptionCount:0
>   07-18 00:17:13.100 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker I/System.out: [CDS]close[51788]
>   07-18 00:17:13.101 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:51788]
>   07-18 00:17:13.103 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker V/Provider/Settings:  from settings cache , name = notification_sound , value = content://media/internal/audio/media/40
>   07-18 00:17:13.103 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker I/RingtoneManager: Get actual default ringtone uri= content://media/internal/audio/media/40
>   07-18 00:17:13.130 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=128KB
>       create new thread
>       new thread created
>       update thread list
>   07-18 00:17:13.132 13333-18017/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: threadid=23: interp stack at 0x63178000
>       threadid=23: created from interp
>   07-18 00:17:13.132 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: start new thread
>   07-18 00:17:13.133 13333-18017/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: threadid=23: notify debugger
>       threadid=23 (UploadServiceIdleTimer): calling run()
>   07-18 00:17:23.133 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/ActivityThread: SVC-Destroying service: net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadService@43929c70
>   07-18 00:17:23.134 13333-17917/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: threadid=17: exiting
>       threadid=17: bye!
>   07-18 00:17:23.136 13333-13333/com.salahahmed.zaker D/ActivityThread: SVC-STOP_SERVICE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@43928498
>   07-18 00:20:04.258 13333-16781/com.salahahmed.zaker D/dalvikvm: threadid=20: exiting
>       threadid=20: bye!

sorry about my log.

Comment: Try to find out what exactly is going wrong (server logs, debugging, ...). Did you get an exception? Which one? What was the stack trace?

Comment: If you try this code it will give you a progress notification after  it finished it gives you " file uploaded successfully"  or "error during upload" so when I upload a large file it takes too much time and after finishing it gives me 
 "error during upload"

Comment: "error during upload" does not help at all to diagnose the problem. A ton of things might have gone wrong. You must dig deeper.

Comment: Use ```exc.printStackTrace()``` in the place of a Toast so you see a full message on Logcat

Comment: Using exc.printStackTrace()  dose not show any thing

Comment: You have to see at Logcat window on AndroidStudio (or adb logcat terminal command) not on device.